# WebDriverError: Unknown error, while opening second edge window using Selenium(Javsacript)

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, selenium-edgedriver

I am creating automation tool for Edge Browser using selenium, where I need to open three edge window with three different URLs parallelly. 
First Edge browser window launch successfully, but when calling function **openEdgeBrowser** for second url, it throws Exception:  **WebDriverError: Unknown error**.

```
const webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');
const edgedriver = require('edgedriver');
const edge = require('selenium-webdriver/edge');


var openEdgeBrowser = async function(url){

    try {
        let edgeService = await new edge.ServiceBuilder(edgedriver.path);
        let browser = await new webdriver.Builder().forBrowser('MicrosoftEdge').setEdgeService(edgeService).build();
        await browser.get(url);
        console.log('Browser launched successfully with url: ' + url);
    } catch(e) {
        console.log.end(`Error in launching edge browser, Exception: ${e}`);
    }
};
```

I expect to run three instances of Edge together.

Comment: Can you show us the code that is invoking this function and a more detailed stack trace?  To me it looks strange that you are not returning a browser object at the end of the function.

Comment: @Ardesco, Thanks for looking into it. At the current state of code, the only target is to open multiple Edge instance, so to keep the code simple I'm not returning browser instance. The sample code, which is invoking this function is  ```let testUrls = ["http://google.com", "http://yahoo.com", "http://facebook.com"];

for (let url of testUrls) {
  openEdgeBrowser (url);
}```

Comment: What happens if you use chrome driver instead of edge driver?  I'm wondering if Edge doesn't like multiple processes...

Comment: On Chrome, its working perfectly. The above code open three windows of chrome with mentioned url. The issue is on Edge. I think, there should be some option or capability, which solve the issue, but unable to figure out.

Comment: OK What version of Windows/Edge are you using.  Older versions of Edge do not support multiple instances

Comment: Microsoft Edge 42.17134.1.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that Edge does not support multiple instances:

> Hi, This is a known issue.
>
> I just checked the Feedback Hub and I only
>   see a Microsoft internal posting for this issue.  Will you add this to
>   the Feedback Hub? Open the Feedback Hub app by using the Search Bar
>   (Win + s) and typing “feedback hub”
>
> The only workaround I am aware of
>   is to use Selenium grid with multiple Windows Clients.  The Clients
>   can be Hyper-V instances.
>
> Appreciate you reporting this issue and wish
>   I had a better answer for you.  :-/ Steve

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/17754737/

The same has also been noted on twitter.

https://twitter.com/instylevii/status/783480823445987329

I can't find any indication that this bug has been fixed, so I'm going to assume it's still outstanding.  It was definitely still outstanding in version 41.16299.15.0 and I can't find anything in the release notes mentioning a fix In version 42.